# Is there visibility issue in golang?

Tags: go

For example, if I update a global variable in one goroutine, then read the variable in another goroutine, can I get the newest value?

Another question is, can "atomic.Load*" and "atomic.Store*" ensure visibility?

Comment: 1. Why don't you try it? It's faster to test it than to post a question. 2. One question per post, please.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without explicit synchronization between goroutines, there is no guarantee that you will see the latest value of a shared variable. The Go memory model describes this:

https://golang.org/ref/mem

Atomic load/store have memory barriers, and they do guarantee you will see the latest value, though the Go memory model does not explicitly state this.